# How can I include an inline search Close button within the search result?

Tags: css, search

The red rectangle delimits inline search result. By clicking outside of it, you exit the search. I would like to include the search close button within the search result though. Is there a way to achieve this?

[image]

It should look like this:
[image]

Link tot the page: http://dev-caal.gotpantheon.com/about

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe wrap your button and search box in a div that is set to relative position. And then have your x button be absolute positioned where you want. Not sure if this is the best way, but it should work

Comment: What exactly is the question? How to add the HTML/CSS or write the JS that will actually close it?